# iTextSharp produces invalid PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Using itextsharp 4.2.0, I have made the following function to generate a dummy PDF in memory and send it back to the client:

```
internal override byte[] GeneratePDFDocument(pdfContent content)
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f);

    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
    document.Open();
    document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
    byte[] response = output.ToArray();
    document.Close();
    return response;
}
```

which is called from a static function:

```
public static byte[] Print(string jsonData)
{
    PDFGeneratorBase generator;
    generator = new ITextSharpGenerator();
    return generator.GeneratePDFDocument(view.GetViewData());
}
```

which is called from a WebAPI controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PrintPDF(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    byte[] pdfData = PrintReport.Print(printJobString);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdfData);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "PrintPDF.pdf";
    return result;
}
```

If I open the resulting PDF in Foxit Reader 7.2, the error message is "Format error: not a PDF or corrupted".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the file read correctly with another reader? Can you check MD5 sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the document before grabbing the byte array. Closing the document flushes the internal buffers of "finishes" the document. Swap this:

```
byte[] response = output.ToArray();
document.Close();
```

With this:

```
document.Close();
byte[] response = output.ToArray();
```